# Getting Stockfish to find all mates-in-n

Tags: engines, stockfish

How do you make Stockfish find all mates in 2 or 3 from a given position? I know I need to use Scid, but not much beyond that.

Comment: What platform are you using? Scid isn't required, any UCI compatible GUI will work with it, and should have instructions on connecting to the Stockfish installation.

Comment: Windows. Is Linux better for the purpose?

Comment: Windows is fine. Winboard should work, as should most modern GUIs,  including commercial ones.

Comment: What about make all possible moves in the position, then check the resulting evaluation? Undo the move, try again. That's simple to script.

Comment: Thanks, but I found my old Fritz program.

Answer (score 3):

Could not be any simpler, run `stockfish`, turn on `MultiPV` option to view all variation, not the only one, then run analysis and you'll get your output, for example for all mate-in-2 I could do this:

```
$ stockfish
Stockfish 09-06-13 64bit by Tord Romstad, Marco Costalba and Joona Kiiski
uci
id name Stockfish 09-06-13 64bit
id author Tord Romstad, Marco Costalba and Joona Kiiski

option name Use Debug Log type check default false
option name Use Search Log type check default false
option name Search Log Filename type string default SearchLog.txt
option name Book File type string default book.bin
option name Best Book Move type check default false
option name Contempt Factor type spin default 0 min -50 max 50
option name Mobility (Middle Game) type spin default 100 min 0 max 200
option name Mobility (Endgame) type spin default 100 min 0 max 200
option name Passed Pawns (Middle Game) type spin default 100 min 0 max 200
option name Passed Pawns (Endgame) type spin default 100 min 0 max 200
option name Space type spin default 100 min 0 max 200
option name Aggressiveness type spin default 100 min 0 max 200
option name Cowardice type spin default 100 min 0 max 200
option name Min Split Depth type spin default 7 min 4 max 12
option name Max Threads per Split Point type spin default 5 min 4 max 8
option name Threads type spin default 8 min 1 max 64
option name Use Sleeping Threads type check default true
option name Hash type spin default 32 min 1 max 8192
option name Clear Hash type button
option name Ponder type check default true
option name OwnBook type check default false
option name MultiPV type spin default 1 min 1 max 500
option name Skill Level type spin default 20 min 0 max 20
option name Emergency Move Horizon type spin default 40 min 0 max 50
option name Emergency Base Time type spin default 200 min 0 max 30000
option name Emergency Move Time type spin default 70 min 0 max 5000
option name Minimum Thinking Time type spin default 20 min 0 max 5000
option name Slow Mover type spin default 100 min 10 max 1000
option name UCI_Chess960 type check default false
option name UCI_AnalyseMode type check default false
uciok
position fen 8/k1K5/2R5/8/8/8/8/8 w - - 0 1
setoption name MultiPV value 100
go depth 10
info depth 1 seldepth 3 score cp 8313 nodes 311 nps 155500 time 2 multipv 1 pv c6c1
info depth 1 seldepth 3 score cp 8313 nodes 311 nps 155500 time 2 multipv 2 pv c6c2
info depth 1 seldepth 3 score cp 8313 nodes 311 nps 155500 time 2 multipv 3 pv c6c3
info depth 1 seldepth 3 score cp 8313 nodes 311 nps 155500 time 2 multipv 4 pv c6c4
info depth 1 seldepth 3 score cp 8313 nodes 311 nps 155500 time 2 multipv 5 pv c6c5
info depth 1 seldepth 3 score cp 8313 nodes 311 nps 155500 time 2 multipv 6 pv c6b6
info depth 1 seldepth 3 score cp 8313 nodes 311 nps 155500 time 2 multipv 7 pv c6d6
info depth 1 seldepth 3 score cp 8313 nodes 311 nps 155500 time 2 multipv 8 pv c6e6
info depth 1 seldepth 3 score cp 8313 nodes 311 nps 155500 time 2 multipv 9 pv c6f6
info depth 1 seldepth 3 score cp 8313 nodes 311 nps 155500 time 2 multipv 10 pv c6g6
info depth 1 seldepth 3 score cp 8313 nodes 311 nps 155500 time 2 multipv 11 pv c6h6
info depth 1 seldepth 3 score cp 8313 nodes 311 nps 155500 time 2 multipv 12 pv c7c8
info depth 1 seldepth 3 score cp 8303 nodes 311 nps 155500 time 2 multipv 13 pv c7d6
info depth 1 seldepth 3 score cp 8303 nodes 311 nps 155500 time 2 multipv 14 pv c7d7
info depth 1 seldepth 3 score cp 8303 nodes 311 nps 155500 time 2 multipv 15 pv c7d8
info depth 1 seldepth 3 score cp 0 nodes 311 nps 155500 time 2 multipv 16 pv c6a6 a7a6
info depth 2 seldepth 3 score mate 2 nodes 989 nps 494500 time 2 multipv 1 pv c6b6 a7a8 b6a6
info depth 2 seldepth 3 score mate 2 nodes 989 nps 494500 time 2 multipv 2 pv c6d6 a7a8 d6a6
info depth 2 seldepth 3 score mate 2 nodes 989 nps 494500 time 2 multipv 3 pv c6e6 a7a8 e6a6
info depth 2 seldepth 3 score mate 2 nodes 989 nps 494500 time 2 multipv 4 pv c6f6 a7a8 f6a6
info depth 2 seldepth 3 score mate 2 nodes 989 nps 494500 time 2 multipv 5 pv c6g6 a7a8 g6a6
info depth 2 seldepth 3 score mate 2 nodes 989 nps 494500 time 2 multipv 6 pv c6h6 a7a8 h6a6
info depth 2 seldepth 3 score mate 2 nodes 989 nps 494500 time 2 multipv 7 pv c7c8 a7a8 c6a6
info depth 2 seldepth 3 score cp 8308 nodes 989 nps 494500 time 2 multipv 8 pv c6c1 a7a6
info depth 2 seldepth 3 score cp 8308 nodes 989 nps 494500 time 2 multipv 9 pv c6c2 a7a6
info depth 2 seldepth 3 score cp 8308 nodes 989 nps 494500 time 2 multipv 10 pv c6c3 a7a6
info depth 2 seldepth 3 score cp 8308 nodes 989 nps 494500 time 2 multipv 11 pv c6c4 a7a6
info depth 2 seldepth 3 score cp 8308 nodes 989 nps 494500 time 2 multipv 12 pv c6c5 a7a6
info depth 2 seldepth 3 score cp 8303 nodes 989 nps 494500 time 2 multipv 13 pv c7d6 a7b7
info depth 2 seldepth 3 score cp 8303 nodes 989 nps 494500 time 2 multipv 14 pv c7d7 a7b7
info depth 2 seldepth 3 score cp 8303 nodes 989 nps 494500 time 2 multipv 15 pv c7d8 a7b7
info depth 2 seldepth 3 score cp 0 nodes 989 nps 494500 time 2 multipv 16 pv c6a6 a7a6
info depth 3 seldepth 4 score mate 2 nodes 1858 nps 929000 time 2 multipv 1 pv c6b6 a7a8 b6a6
info depth 3 seldepth 4 score mate 2 nodes 1858 nps 929000 time 2 multipv 2 pv c6d6 a7a8 d6a6
info depth 3 seldepth 4 score mate 2 nodes 1858 nps 929000 time 2 multipv 3 pv c6e6 a7a8 e6a6
info depth 3 seldepth 4 score mate 2 nodes 1858 nps 929000 time 2 multipv 4 pv c6f6 a7a8 f6a6
info depth 3 seldepth 4 score mate 2 nodes 1858 nps 929000 time 2 multipv 5 pv c6g6 a7a8 g6a6
info depth 3 seldepth 4 score mate 2 nodes 1858 nps 929000 time 2 multipv 6 pv c6h6 a7a8 h6a6
info depth 3 seldepth 4 score mate 2 nodes 1858 nps 929000 time 2 multipv 7 pv c7c8 a7a8 c6a6
info depth 3 seldepth 4 score cp 8308 nodes 1858 nps 929000 time 2 multipv 8 pv c6c1 a7a6 c1b1
info depth 3 seldepth 4 score cp 8308 nodes 1858 nps 929000 time 2 multipv 9 pv c6c2 a7a6 c2c1
info depth 3 seldepth 4 score cp 8308 nodes 1858 nps 929000 time 2 multipv 10 pv c6c3 a7a6 c3c1
info depth 3 seldepth 4 score cp 8308 nodes 1858 nps 929000 time 2 multipv 11 pv c6c4 a7a6 c4c1
info depth 3 seldepth 4 score cp 8308 nodes 1858 nps 929000 time 2 multipv 12 pv c6c5 a7a6 c5c1
info depth 3 seldepth 4 score cp 8303 nodes 1858 nps 929000 time 2 multipv 13 pv c7d6 a7b7 c6c1
info depth 3 seldepth 4 score cp 8303 nodes 1858 nps 929000 time 2 multipv 14 pv c7d7 a7b7 c6c1
info depth 3 seldepth 4 score cp 8303 nodes 1858 nps 929000 time 2 multipv 15 pv c7d8 a7b7 c6c1
info depth 3 seldepth 4 score cp 0 nodes 1858 nps 929000 time 2 multipv 16 pv c6a6 a7a6
info depth 4 seldepth 4 score mate 2 nodes 3184 nps 1061333 time 3 multipv 1 pv c6b6 a7a8 b6a6
info depth 4 seldepth 4 score mate 2 nodes 3184 nps 1061333 time 3 multipv 2 pv c6d6 a7a8 d6a6
info depth 4 seldepth 4 score mate 2 nodes 3184 nps 1061333 time 3 multipv 3 pv c6e6 a7a8 e6a6
info depth 4 seldepth 4 score mate 2 nodes 3184 nps 1061333 time 3 multipv 4 pv c6f6 a7a8 f6a6
info depth 4 seldepth 4 score mate 2 nodes 3184 nps 1061333 time 3 multipv 5 pv c6g6 a7a8 g6a6
info depth 4 seldepth 4 score mate 2 nodes 3184 nps 1061333 time 3 multipv 6 pv c6h6 a7a8 h6a6
info depth 4 seldepth 4 score mate 2 nodes 3184 nps 1061333 time 3 multipv 7 pv c7c8 a7a8 c6a6
info depth 4 seldepth 4 score mate 3 nodes 3184 nps 1061333 time 3 multipv 8 pv c6c1 a7a6 c1c5 a6a7 c5a5
info depth 4 seldepth 4 score mate 3 nodes 3184 nps 1061333 time 3 multipv 9 pv c6c2 a7a6 c2c5 a6a7 c5a5
info depth 4 seldepth 4 score mate 3 nodes 3184 nps 1061333 time 3 multipv 10 pv c6c3 a7a6 c3c5 a6a7 c5a5
info depth 4 seldepth 4 score mate 3 nodes 3184 nps 1061333 time 3 multipv 11 pv c6c4 a7a6 c4c5 a6a7 c5a5
info depth 4 seldepth 4 score mate 3 nodes 3184 nps 1061333 time 3 multipv 12 pv c6c5 a7a6 c5d5 a6a7 d5a5
info depth 4 seldepth 4 score cp 8303 nodes 3184 nps 1061333 time 3 multipv 13 pv c7d6 a7b7 d6c5 b7b8
info depth 4 seldepth 4 score cp 8303 nodes 3184 nps 1061333 time 3 multipv 14 pv c7d7 a7b7 c6d6 b7a7
info depth 4 seldepth 4 score cp 8303 nodes 3184 nps 1061333 time 3 multipv 15 pv c7d8 a7b7 c6d6 b7a7
info depth 4 seldepth 4 score cp 0 nodes 3184 nps 1061333 time 3 multipv 16 pv c6a6 a7a6
info depth 5 seldepth 7 score mate 2 nodes 4801 nps 1200250 time 4 multipv 1 pv c6b6 a7a8 b6a6
info depth 5 seldepth 7 score mate 2 nodes 4801 nps 1200250 time 4 multipv 2 pv c6d6 a7a8 d6a6
info depth 5 seldepth 7 score mate 2 nodes 4801 nps 1200250 time 4 multipv 3 pv c6e6 a7a8 e6a6
info depth 5 seldepth 7 score mate 2 nodes 4801 nps 1200250 time 4 multipv 4 pv c6f6 a7a8 f6a6
info depth 5 seldepth 7 score mate 2 nodes 4801 nps 1200250 time 4 multipv 5 pv c6g6 a7a8 g6a6
info depth 5 seldepth 7 score mate 2 nodes 4801 nps 1200250 time 4 multipv 6 pv c6h6 a7a8 h6a6
info depth 5 seldepth 7 score mate 2 nodes 4801 nps 1200250 time 4 multipv 7 pv c7c8 a7a8 c6a6
info depth 5 seldepth 7 score mate 3 nodes 4801 nps 1200250 time 4 multipv 8 pv c6c1 a7a6 c1c5 a6a7 c5a5
info depth 5 seldepth 7 score mate 3 nodes 4801 nps 1200250 time 4 multipv 9 pv c6c2 a7a6 c2c5 a6a7 c5a5
info depth 5 seldepth 7 score mate 3 nodes 4801 nps 1200250 time 4 multipv 10 pv c6c3 a7a6 c3c5 a6a7 c5a5
info depth 5 seldepth 7 score mate 3 nodes 4801 nps 1200250 time 4 multipv 11 pv c6c4 a7a6 c4c5 a6a7 c5a5
info depth 5 seldepth 7 score mate 3 nodes 4801 nps 1200250 time 4 multipv 12 pv c6c5 a7a6 c5d5 a6a7 d5a5
info depth 5 seldepth 7 score cp 8313 nodes 4801 nps 1200250 time 4 multipv 13 pv c7d6 a7b7 d6c5 b7b8 c5b6
info depth 5 seldepth 7 score cp 8313 nodes 4801 nps 1200250 time 4 multipv 14 pv c7d7 a7b7 c6d6 b7b8 d6a6
info depth 5 seldepth 7 score cp 8313 nodes 4801 nps 1200250 time 4 multipv 15 pv c7d8 a7b7 c6d6 b7b8 d6a6
info depth 5 seldepth 7 score cp 0 nodes 4801 nps 1200250 time 4 multipv 16 pv c6a6 a7a6
info depth 6 seldepth 7 score mate 2 nodes 6642 nps 1660500 time 4 multipv 1 pv c6b6 a7a8 b6a6
info depth 6 seldepth 7 score mate 2 nodes 6642 nps 1660500 time 4 multipv 2 pv c6d6 a7a8 d6a6
info depth 6 seldepth 7 score mate 2 nodes 6642 nps 1660500 time 4 multipv 3 pv c6e6 a7a8 e6a6
info depth 6 seldepth 7 score mate 2 nodes 6642 nps 1660500 time 4 multipv 4 pv c6f6 a7a8 f6a6
info depth 6 seldepth 7 score mate 2 nodes 6642 nps 1660500 time 4 multipv 5 pv c6g6 a7a8 g6a6
info depth 6 seldepth 7 score mate 2 nodes 6642 nps 1660500 time 4 multipv 6 pv c6h6 a7a8 h6a6
info depth 6 seldepth 7 score mate 2 nodes 6642 nps 1660500 time 4 multipv 7 pv c7c8 a7a8 c6a6
info depth 6 seldepth 7 score mate 3 nodes 6642 nps 1660500 time 4 multipv 8 pv c6c1 a7a6 c1c5 a6a7 c5a5
info depth 6 seldepth 7 score mate 3 nodes 6642 nps 1660500 time 4 multipv 9 pv c6c2 a7a6 c2c5 a6a7 c5a5
info depth 6 seldepth 7 score mate 3 nodes 6642 nps 1660500 time 4 multipv 10 pv c6c3 a7a6 c3c5 a6a7 c5a5
info depth 6 seldepth 7 score mate 3 nodes 6642 nps 1660500 time 4 multipv 11 pv c6c4 a7a6 c4c5 a6a7 c5a5
info depth 6 seldepth 7 score mate 3 nodes 6642 nps 1660500 time 4 multipv 12 pv c6c5 a7a6 c5d5 a6a7 d5a5
info depth 6 seldepth 7 score cp 8308 nodes 6642 nps 1660500 time 4 multipv 13 pv c7d6 a7b7 d6c5 b7a7 c6b6 a7a8
info depth 6 seldepth 7 score cp 8308 nodes 6642 nps 1660500 time 4 multipv 14 pv c7d7 a7b7 c6d6 b7b8 d7c6 b8c8
info depth 6 seldepth 7 score cp 8308 nodes 6642 nps 1660500 time 4 multipv 15 pv c7d8 a7b7 c6d6 b7b8 d6d7 b8a8
info depth 6 seldepth 7 score cp 0 nodes 6642 nps 1660500 time 4 multipv 16 pv c6a6 a7a6
info depth 7 seldepth 8 score mate 2 nodes 9342 nps 1557000 time 6 multipv 1 pv c6b6 a7a8 b6a6
info depth 7 seldepth 8 score mate 2 nodes 9342 nps 1557000 time 6 multipv 2 pv c6d6 a7a8 d6a6
info depth 7 seldepth 8 score mate 2 nodes 9342 nps 1557000 time 6 multipv 3 pv c6e6 a7a8 e6a6
info depth 7 seldepth 8 score mate 2 nodes 9342 nps 1557000 time 6 multipv 4 pv c6f6 a7a8 f6a6
info depth 7 seldepth 8 score mate 2 nodes 9342 nps 1557000 time 6 multipv 5 pv c6g6 a7a8 g6a6
info depth 7 seldepth 8 score mate 2 nodes 9342 nps 1557000 time 6 multipv 6 pv c6h6 a7a8 h6a6
info depth 7 seldepth 8 score mate 2 nodes 9342 nps 1557000 time 6 multipv 7 pv c7c8 a7a8 c6a6
info depth 7 seldepth 8 score mate 3 nodes 9342 nps 1557000 time 6 multipv 8 pv c6c1 a7a6 c1c5 a6a7 c5a5
info depth 7 seldepth 8 score mate 3 nodes 9342 nps 1557000 time 6 multipv 9 pv c6c2 a7a6 c2c5 a6a7 c5a5
info depth 7 seldepth 8 score mate 3 nodes 9342 nps 1557000 time 6 multipv 10 pv c6c3 a7a6 c3c5 a6a7 c5a5
info depth 7 seldepth 8 score mate 3 nodes 9342 nps 1557000 time 6 multipv 11 pv c6c4 a7a6 c4c5 a6a7 c5a5
info depth 7 seldepth 8 score mate 3 nodes 9342 nps 1557000 time 6 multipv 12 pv c6c5 a7a6 c5d5 a6a7 d5a5
info depth 7 seldepth 8 score cp 8318 nodes 9342 nps 1557000 time 6 multipv 13 pv c7d8 a7b7 c6d6 b7b8 d6d7 b8a8 d8c7
info depth 7 seldepth 8 score cp 8313 nodes 9342 nps 1557000 time 6 multipv 14 pv c7d6 a7b7 d6c5 b7a8 c5b6 a8b8 c6c7
info depth 7 seldepth 8 score cp 8313 nodes 9342 nps 1557000 time 6 multipv 15 pv c7d7 a7b7 c6d6 b7b8 d6b6 b8a8 d7c7 a8a7
info depth 7 seldepth 8 score cp 0 nodes 9342 nps 1557000 time 6 multipv 16 pv c6a6 a7a6
info depth 8 seldepth 11 score mate 2 nodes 11643 nps 1455375 time 8 multipv 1 pv c6b6 a7a8 b6a6
info depth 8 seldepth 11 score mate 2 nodes 11643 nps 1455375 time 8 multipv 2 pv c6d6 a7a8 d6a6
info depth 8 seldepth 11 score mate 2 nodes 11643 nps 1455375 time 8 multipv 3 pv c6e6 a7a8 e6a6
info depth 8 seldepth 11 score mate 2 nodes 11643 nps 1455375 time 8 multipv 4 pv c6f6 a7a8 f6a6
info depth 8 seldepth 11 score mate 2 nodes 11643 nps 1455375 time 8 multipv 5 pv c6g6 a7a8 g6a6
info depth 8 seldepth 11 score mate 2 nodes 11643 nps 1455375 time 8 multipv 6 pv c6h6 a7a8 h6a6
info depth 8 seldepth 11 score mate 2 nodes 11643 nps 1455375 time 8 multipv 7 pv c7c8 a7a8 c6a6
info depth 8 seldepth 11 score mate 3 nodes 11643 nps 1455375 time 8 multipv 8 pv c6c1 a7a6 c1c5 a6a7 c5a5
info depth 8 seldepth 11 score mate 3 nodes 11643 nps 1455375 time 8 multipv 9 pv c6c2 a7a6 c2c5 a6a7 c5a5
info depth 8 seldepth 11 score mate 3 nodes 11643 nps 1455375 time 8 multipv 10 pv c6c3 a7a6 c3c5 a6a7 c5a5
info depth 8 seldepth 11 score mate 3 nodes 11643 nps 1455375 time 8 multipv 11 pv c6c4 a7a6 c4c5 a6a7 c5a5
info depth 8 seldepth 11 score mate 3 nodes 11643 nps 1455375 time 8 multipv 12 pv c6c5 a7a6 c5d5 a6a7 d5a5
info depth 8 seldepth 11 score mate 6 nodes 11643 nps 1455375 time 8 multipv 13 pv c7d8 a7b7 c6d6 b7b8 d6b6 b8a8 d8c8 a8a7 c8c7 a7a8 b6a6
info depth 8 seldepth 11 score mate 6 nodes 11643 nps 1455375 time 8 multipv 14 pv c7d6 a7b7 d6c5 b7a7 c6c7 a7a8 c5b5 a8b8 b5b6 b8a8 c7c8
info depth 8 seldepth 11 score mate 6 nodes 11643 nps 1455375 time 8 multipv 15 pv c7d7 a7b7 c6d6 b7b8 d6b6 b8a8 d7c7 a8a7 b6d6 a7a8 d6a6
info depth 8 seldepth 11 score cp 0 nodes 11643 nps 1455375 time 8 multipv 16 pv c6a6 a7a6
info depth 9 seldepth 11 score mate 2 nodes 13599 nps 1359900 time 10 multipv 1 pv c6b6 a7a8 b6a6
info depth 9 seldepth 11 score mate 2 nodes 13599 nps 1359900 time 10 multipv 2 pv c6d6 a7a8 d6a6
info depth 9 seldepth 11 score mate 2 nodes 13599 nps 1359900 time 10 multipv 3 pv c6e6 a7a8 e6a6
info depth 9 seldepth 11 score mate 2 nodes 13599 nps 1359900 time 10 multipv 4 pv c6f6 a7a8 f6a6
info depth 9 seldepth 11 score mate 2 nodes 13599 nps 1359900 time 10 multipv 5 pv c6g6 a7a8 g6a6
info depth 9 seldepth 11 score mate 2 nodes 13599 nps 1359900 time 10 multipv 6 pv c6h6 a7a8 h6a6
info depth 9 seldepth 11 score mate 2 nodes 13599 nps 1359900 time 10 multipv 7 pv c7c8 a7a8 c6a6
info depth 9 seldepth 11 score mate 3 nodes 13599 nps 1359900 time 10 multipv 8 pv c6c1 a7a6 c1c5 a6a7 c5a5
info depth 9 seldepth 11 score mate 3 nodes 13599 nps 1359900 time 10 multipv 9 pv c6c2 a7a6 c2c5 a6a7 c5a5
info depth 9 seldepth 11 score mate 3 nodes 13599 nps 1359900 time 10 multipv 10 pv c6c3 a7a6 c3c5 a6a7 c5a5
info depth 9 seldepth 11 score mate 3 nodes 13599 nps 1359900 time 10 multipv 11 pv c6c4 a7a6 c4c5 a6a7 c5a5
info depth 9 seldepth 11 score mate 3 nodes 13599 nps 1359900 time 10 multipv 12 pv c6c5 a7a6 c5d5 a6a7 d5a5
info depth 9 seldepth 11 score mate 6 nodes 13599 nps 1359900 time 10 multipv 13 pv c7d8 a7b7 c6d6 b7b8 d6b6 b8a8 d8c8 a8a7 c8c7 a7a8 b6a6
info depth 9 seldepth 11 score mate 6 nodes 13599 nps 1359900 time 10 multipv 14 pv c7d6 a7b7 d6c5 b7a7 c6c7 a7a8 c5b5 a8b8 b5b6 b8a8 c7c8
info depth 9 seldepth 11 score mate 6 nodes 13599 nps 1359900 time 10 multipv 15 pv c7d7 a7b7 c6d6 b7b8 d6b6 b8a8 d7c7 a8a7 b6d6 a7a8 d6a6
info depth 9 seldepth 11 score cp 0 nodes 13599 nps 1359900 time 10 multipv 16 pv c6a6 a7a6
info depth 10 seldepth 12 score mate 2 nodes 15888 nps 1324000 time 12 multipv 1 pv c6b6 a7a8 b6a6
info depth 10 seldepth 12 score mate 2 nodes 15888 nps 1324000 time 12 multipv 2 pv c6d6 a7a8 d6a6
info depth 10 seldepth 12 score mate 2 nodes 15888 nps 1324000 time 12 multipv 3 pv c6e6 a7a8 e6a6
info depth 10 seldepth 12 score mate 2 nodes 15888 nps 1324000 time 12 multipv 4 pv c6f6 a7a8 f6a6
info depth 10 seldepth 12 score mate 2 nodes 15888 nps 1324000 time 12 multipv 5 pv c6g6 a7a8 g6a6
info depth 10 seldepth 12 score mate 2 nodes 15888 nps 1324000 time 12 multipv 6 pv c6h6 a7a8 h6a6
info depth 10 seldepth 12 score mate 2 nodes 15888 nps 1324000 time 12 multipv 7 pv c7c8 a7a8 c6a6
info depth 10 seldepth 12 score mate 3 nodes 15888 nps 1324000 time 12 multipv 8 pv c6c1 a7a6 c1c5 a6a7 c5a5
info depth 10 seldepth 12 score mate 3 nodes 15888 nps 1324000 time 12 multipv 9 pv c6c2 a7a6 c2c5 a6a7 c5a5
info depth 10 seldepth 12 score mate 3 nodes 15888 nps 1324000 time 12 multipv 10 pv c6c3 a7a6 c3c5 a6a7 c5a5
info depth 10 seldepth 12 score mate 3 nodes 15888 nps 1324000 time 12 multipv 11 pv c6c4 a7a6 c4c5 a6a7 c5a5
info depth 10 seldepth 12 score mate 3 nodes 15888 nps 1324000 time 12 multipv 12 pv c6c5 a7a6 c5d5 a6a7 d5a5
info depth 10 seldepth 12 score mate 6 nodes 15888 nps 1324000 time 12 multipv 13 pv c7d8 a7b7 c6d6 b7b8 d6b6 b8a8 d8c8 a8a7 c8c7 a7a8 b6a6
info depth 10 seldepth 12 score mate 6 nodes 15888 nps 1324000 time 12 multipv 14 pv c7d6 a7b7 d6c5 b7a7 c6c7 a7a8 c5b5 a8b8 b5b6 b8a8 c7c8
info depth 10 seldepth 12 score mate 6 nodes 15888 nps 1324000 time 12 multipv 15 pv c7d7 a7b7 c6d6 b7b8 d6b6 b8a8 d7c7 a8a7 b6d6 a7a8 d6a6
info depth 10 seldepth 12 score cp 0 nodes 15888 nps 1324000 time 12 multipv 16 pv c6a6 a7a6
info nodes 15888 time 12
bestmove c6b6 ponder a7a8
```